# PHP recursive array from JSON to key-value to values

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb

I want to apologize in advanced if this was already asked, I'm not exactly sure what this would be called.

---

I'm storing data from a form into a MongoDB database and I'd like to create defined key-value pairs to make sorting easier.

Using this code I am able to do this with a one-dimensional array, but it does not work with multidimensional arrays:

```
/* $array = The array */
$new_array = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    array_push($new_array, array(
        'name' => $key,
        'value' => $value
    ));
}
```

**Example:**

Input array:

```
Array
(
    [email] => test@mail.com
    [name] => John
    [sports] => Array
        (
            [outdoor] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Football
                    [1] => Baseball
                )

            [indoor] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Basketball
                    [1] => Hockey
                )
        )
)
```

Output array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => email
            [value] => test@mail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [value] => John
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => sports
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [outdoor] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Football
                            [1] => Baseball
                        )

                    [indoor] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Basketball
                            [1] => Hockey
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Notice how it stops at the sports value array and does not change the array within it.  How can I continue this pattern throughout all the arrays within it?

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service, you have to give it a try yourself and post your code.

Comment: @Barmar Sure.  Right now I'm able to do this with a one-dimensional array.  I will post the code in a minute.

Comment: you mean like `json_decode($array,true)`?

Comment: @Dave Chen That is what my input is array is.  I now need to convert that to the above example.

Comment: Provide the example of multidimensional array and the result that you with you get

Comment: @claustrofob I have attempted to clarify my example.  Please tell me if I can add anything else to clarify further (if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
function keyValue($array){
  $new_array = array();

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      array_push($new_array, array(
          'name' => $key,
          'value' => is_array($value) ? keyValue($value) : $value
      ));
  }

  return $new_array;
}
```

Comment: This almost works as desired, however the last array in the "tree" (the deepest) should just be `Array([name] => outdoor [value] => Array([0] => Football [1] => Baseball))`.  I will just check to see if here is an array in the array, and will stop if there isn't.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this on for size:

```
$array = array(
    'email' => 'test@email.com',
    'name' => 'John',
    'sport' => array('Soccor', 'Hockey')
);

$func = function($value, $key) {

     $return = array();
     $return['name'] = $key;
     $return['value'] = $value;


    return $return;
};

$parsed = array_map($func, $array, array_keys($array));
```

For me, this returned:

```
   array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "email"
    ["value"]=>
    string(14) "test@email.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "John"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "sport"
    ["value"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["outdoor"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(8) "Football"
        [1]=>
        string(8) "Baseball"
      }
      ["indoor"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(10) "Basketball"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "Hockey"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works as well but, like my first example, doesn't work recursively.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple to turn associative arrays to JSON objects (StdClass) and vice versa, preserving native data types (int, float, bool). Here's my attempt:

**To Key-Value Array**

```
function toKeyValue($values)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($values as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result[$key] = toKeyValue($value);
        } elseif (is_object($value)) {
            $result[$key] = toKeyValue((array) $value);
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**To JSON Object**

```
function toJson($values)
{
   return json_decode(json_encode($values));
}
```

> `$values` should always be an array.